# Evaluation of the method working with the DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some method interacting with the DataFrame and returning the number I need.

```
     private def getExpectedPartitionBytes(df: DataFrame, partitionNames: Seq[String] = Seq())
                                          (implicit spark: SparkSession): Long = {
    
        val partitionsCount = df.select(partitionNames.map(c => col(c)): _*).dropDuplicates.count
           
        val expectedTotalBytes = df.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.stats(spark.sessionState.conf)
                                                                .sizeInBytes.toLong
    
        val expectedPartitionBytes = expectedTotalBytes / partitionsCount
        // dirty estimation from dataframe dimension
        // real size of types divided on two
        val maxExpectedPartitionBytes = df.dtypes.filter(t => !partitionNames.contains(t._1)).map(_._2).map {
          case "StringType" => 10
          case "ByteType" => 1
          case "ShortType" => 2
          case "IntegerType" => 4
          case "LongType" => 8
          case "FloatType" => 4
          case "DoubleType" => 8
          case "TimestampType" => 6
          case _ => 2
        }.sum * df.count / partitionsCount
    
    
        if (expectedTotalBytes > 0 && expectedPartitionBytes <= maxExpectedPartitionBytes) {
          // if plan estimation is exists and real
          expectedPartitionBytes
        } else {
          maxExpectedPartitionBytes
        }
      }
```

I have a question regarding the performance of this method.
We all know that DataFrame works lazily.
First, Spark registers the calculations that need to be performed on the DataFrame. Then, when we request the result of the calculation, Spark gets to work.
In this regard, I want to ask you. Please explain at what point in my example the DataFrame calculations are started.

At the moment when we assign a value to a variable?

```
val partitionsCount = df.select(partitionNames.map(c => col(c)): _*).dropDuplicates.count
```

Or at the moment when the method tries to return a number to us?

```
if (expectedTotalBytes > 0 && expectedPartitionBytes <= maxExpectedPartitionBytes) {
          // if plan estimation is exists and real
          expectedPartitionBytes
        } else {
          maxExpectedPartitionBytes
        }
```

Or maybe the count will start when dividing?

```
}.sum * df.count / partitionsCount
```

And I would also like to know about the possibility of optimizing my method. Can I somehow rationally use `checkpoint()` or `cache()` for my DataFrame to reduce unnecessary calculations?
And how do I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please explain at what point in my example the DataFrame calculations are started.

The value of `partitionCount` is evaluated immediately, as the `count` call is an 'action'. If you wanted to defer evaluation you could declare a lazy variable in Scala:

```
lazy val partitionCount = df.count 
partitionCount: Long = <lazy>
```

You'll see that the type is of `Long` as expected, but there is no associated value. Once you access the `val` for the first time the expression will be evaluated.

> Can I somehow rationally use checkpoint() or cache() for my DataFrame to reduce unnecessary calculations?

Looking at the code you have provided you are not undertaking any duplicate work.